# How to make focus work in Mozila Firefox same as in Google chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a input field, if i click on that focus is present on that, if i delete the content fully in it it stays like this in Google chrome.

[image: Working with Google chrome]

But in Mozila Firefox, if i delete content fully then it shows like this,

[image: Working with Mozila Firefox], but if i type anything then focus comes as in google chrome.

Can anyone please help me to get focus in Mozila Firefox as it is with google chrome when all contents are deleted.

I am hereby sharing HTMl and CSS code:

```css
h2.title.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.focused,
h2.title.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-empty,
h2.title.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-not-empty,
h2.title.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.focused.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse,
h2.title.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-empty {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 35px 45px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title" contenteditable="true" ng-model="section.title" ng-focus="focusData.current_focus_index=$index" ng-blur="blurFn($event,$index)" ng-class="{ focused: (focusData.current_focus_index == $index)}" unselectable="on" ng-keydown="disable_enter($event,$index)"
  ng-change="check_section_title($index)"></h2>
```